# Can a path wind around it's unbounded connected compnenet?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Let $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a closed path, if needed it may be assumed to be continuously differentiable. the complement of the image of $\gamma$ may be represented by it's (open) connected componenets $(Im \gamma) ^C = \bigcup _{n = 1}^\infty U_n$, since $Im \gamma$ is compact, there exists a single componenet $U_{n_0}$ which is unbounded.

**My question is whether it is known that $\gamma$ doesn't wind around points in $U_{n_0}$**. In the case that $\gamma$ is a simple path, I think it is part of the jordan curve theorem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, we can decompose into simple paths and apply the Jordan curve theorem. Cycles suffice to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping $z \mapsto I(\gamma, z)$ is *constant* in each connected component of $\operatorname{Im}(\gamma)^C$ (because it is integer-valued and continuous). In particular, for all $z$ in the unbounded component
$$
I(\gamma, z) = \lim_{w \to \infty}I(\gamma, w)
= \lim_{w \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - w} = 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Great answer, easier than I thought.